# Qt and variadic functions

Tags: c++, qt, variadic-functions

OK, before lecturing me on the use of C-style variadic functions in C++...everything else has turned out to require nothing short of rewriting the Qt MOC.

What I'd like to know is whether or not you can have a "slot" in a Qt object that takes an arbitrary amount/type of arguments.  The thing is that I really want to be able to generate Qt objects that have slots of an arbitrary signature.  Since the MOC is incompatible with standard preprocessing and with templates, it's not possible to do so with either direct approach.  I just came up with another idea:

```
struct funky_base : QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  funky_base(QObject * o = 0);

public slots:
  virtual void the_slot(...) = 0;
};
```

If this is possible then, because you can make a template that is a subclass of a QObject derived object so long as you don't declare new Qt stuff in it, I should be able to implement a derived templated type that takes the `...` stuff and turns it into the appropriate, expected types.

If it is, how would I connect to it?  Would this work?

```
connect(x, SIGNAL(someSignal(int)), y, SLOT(the_slot(...)));
```

If nobody's tried anything this insane and doesn't know off hand, yes I'll eventually try it myself...but I am hoping someone already has existing knowledge I can tap before possibly wasting my time on it.

---

This question was an attempt to find a way to design a 'catch-all' base class for a templated object that could translate Qt signals into static signals like boost::signals2 or just basic functions.  I thought if I could construct a slot that took variadic templates I could use TMP to reconstruct the parameters out of the va_args.  The answer to the problem was pretty much exactly that but cuts in BEFORE the slot gets called by the qt mechanism.  The first installment of an article series on how to make the whole thing showed how I solved this part of the problem:

http://crazyeddiecpp.blogspot.com/2011/01/quest-for-sane-signals-in-qt-step-1.html

That's my old blog location.  New one's in my profile if you want to see other weird sh1t.

Comment: NVM, I answered my own question.  Qt is of course not able to do this either.

Comment: By having untyped slots you're giving away one of the core advantages of the language ... compile-time type safety.

Comment: Frank, frank, frank.  Qt's already done that.  I'm trying to get type safety back.  This was one, failed, attempt.  See my blog for the eventual success story (it's on my profile).

Comment: You should pos the answer then so others can see it here :)

Comment: It seems you'd be better off trying the Qt flavor for variadic args as signal parameters: QList<QVariant>

Comment: @Michael - suppose you're right, especially since I changed blog location and there's no linkback.

Comment: So where is the answer ? Or are you posting a difficult question that you know the answer to in order to promote your blog and build reputation :P ?

Comment: You can read how I solved it at my blog, accept that my first comment IS the answer, or just ignore it.  Anything else is to be quickly filed into the folder labeled, not my f'n problem.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: As it hasn't been mentioned here (neither from you), don't do variadic functions in C++. Apart from all other reasons not to, you enter the Dark Realm Of Undefined Behaviour as soon as you pass a non-POD type to The Dreaded Ellipses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently people keep thinking this question is still in need of answer because several weeks after I asked it and then answered it myself, people are still posting their responses.  So I guess I have to make it explicitly an answer instead of both in the question itself and the first comment for it:

You can't use a variadic function as a signal or slot in Qt.

I spent a lot of time and effort not only solving the problem and sharing it, but explaining HOW the problem was solved.  Please consider reading, you might even learn something new.

Comment: It is not a problem on SO to answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Everything to solve this problem will be ugly, but you shouldn't have to do all the heavy lifting yourself.  You can use [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/any.html) or [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/variant.html) as the argument type and then roll an object to contain the arguments you need (or use a vector of any/variant types).

You can also use QVariant, but it's not as nice as boost::variant, and certainly not as flexible (for a price) as boost::any.

(Or just rewrite Qt with boost::signals or the trX:: variant, as we now live in the 21st century.  Also, don't really rag too much on the Qt developers for the state of signals/slots - the C++-features that boost::signals uses were not commonly supported by C++ compilers when Trolltech developed their implementation of signal/slots).

Answer (score -1):

Note that "..." constructions can't take "real" objects, because C++ never bothered to extend the "..." syntax.

That's actually sort of good news in your case, because it means the following suggestion might actually work for you without having to worry about C++ auto-destructing your objects.

What you could do is create a simple object whose constructor takes a "...".  It would walk through its arguments, dumping them into a dynamically allocated array.  Then you could pass that single object to the slot.

Let's say you're a lazy typist and called that object V (for variant or variadic or whatever).    Then you could call a function that takes V like this:

```
function(V("one", "two", "three", NULL));
```

Of course, every caller would have to construct V by hand, which perhaps isn't exactly what you were hoping for.

Comment: I didn't vote this down but "not having to worry about C++ auto-destructing your objects" is a rather dangerous statement. Otherwise I'd agree for the most part. C++ objects with destructors are supposed to be destroyed automatically. To not have that is bypassing a fundamental mechanism in the language.